# VB.Net CType Class to Enum

Tags: vb.net, enums, type-conversion

I'm trying to create a class that can be CType'd to different types:

```
Option Strict Off

Public Class CInteger
    Private Value As Integer
    Public Sub New(value As Integer)
        Me.Value = value
    End Sub
    Public Shared Widening Operator CType(ByVal value As CInteger) As Integer
        Return value.Value
    End Operator
    'Commenting next operator makes compilation without errors
    Public Shared Widening Operator CType(ByVal value As CInteger) As String
        Return value.Value
    End Operator
End Class

Public Enum EEnum1 As Integer
    First = 1
End Enum
Public Enum EEnum2 As Integer
    First = 1
End Enum

Private Sub Test()
    Dim e1 As EEnum1 = New CInteger(1)
    Dim e2 As EEnum2 = New CInteger(1)
End Sub
```

It works fine converting to Enums if there's only and Integer operator defined, but when I try to add any other operator the compiler throws errors because the conversion can't be done.
I can neither change the Enum declarations nor declare CType operator for each Enum, is it posible to workaround this?

Comment: Maybe you want `Public Shared Widening Operator CType(ByVal value As Integer) As CInteger Return New CInteger(value) End Operator`. With Option Strict OFF. It can map to `DirectCast(New CInteger(1).Value, EEnum1)` etc (with `Value` set to `public`) when Option Strict ON, which makes the Type somewhat *mute*.

Comment: But the problem is that my class (CInteger) is not castable to Enum, how is this going to help? I've tried it anyway and the error message is the same

Comment: Maybe because you have changed the string Type result in the same way. Note that the Integer Type return value is inverted in the snippet I've posted. The `String` return Type remains the same, otherwise nobody knows what king of Type you want to return, hence the error (with Option Strict OFF, of course, which is not exactly a good idea).

Comment: You ca probably also change the definition of your Type (e.g., `Public Class CInteger(Of T)`) and have, e.g., `Public Shared Widening Operator CType(value As CInteger(Of T)) As Integer Return value.Value End Operator`. The you can write `Dim e1 As EEnum1 = New CInteger(Of EEnum1)(1)` -- Still with Option Strict OFF, which causes an implicit cast.

Comment: Yes I've noticed how you've posted your first code snippet, but I've tried adding it in my example (copy-pasted) and it doesn't change anything, the error is the same. And I can't change the declaration of my class to use generics, because I need to be able to initialize it without knowing type. It would be nice if generics where available in CType operators, something like     Public Shared Widening Operator CType(ByVal value As CInteger) As Enum(Of T)

Comment: That code is meant to replace what you have written, not add to it. The reason why your attempt fails is because it cannot be determined which operator to use, so you need to make them different (different parameters). -- It's not clear, to me at least, what is the use of this class. It should be generic and Option Strict ON compliant, but, as you probably know, there's a problem with generics and Enumerators in VB.Net, so it may seem a bit contrived, even though possible.

Comment: I've tried replacing the code instead of adding it, but the problem is the same, it's not possible to cast my class to any Enum. I know the problem is that I haven't declared an explicit CType operator for each Enum, but why does it work when there's only an Integer CType and not when there's any other one? I'm using this class to migrate an old VB application to .Net and emulate Variant type; at first I had everything working with Object type but comparing nulls (DBNull.Value) with other values was a problem, so I started with this class and the only problem I have is casting to Enums